# New MacBook Pro hard drive not being recognized by Disk Utility?

Tags: hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro

Hey all. Recently I had the misfortune of having (what I think was) hard drive failure on my September 2009 MacBook Pro. When I started the computer, a flashing folder icon with a question mark appeared.

I booted from the Snow Leopard install disk and ran Disk Utility to see if I could repair the drive. Disk Utility didn't even show the drive, just the install DVD. After a few hours of the laptop being off, I was able to start it normally and copy most of my important files to an external hard drive before the OS froze, and subsequent reboots showed a flashing folder icon.

I bought a replacement drive, the [Western Digital Scorpio Black](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.asp?driveid=477) and installed it by following [these](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,2363244,00.asp) instructions. Installation was pretty straightforward, but all was not well.

When I booted the laptop using the install disk as a startup disk, it could not recognize my new hard drive as a viable installation disk. It didn't show up in Disk Utility, and when I went to install the OS, the drive was not available for selection as an installation drive. Is this something more sinister than hard drive failure? Any suggestions on what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable that connects the hard drive to the logic board could be bad(or various other problems with the board). Your best bet is to take it into an Apple store so the techs there can run ASD. When parts aren't recognized by the system, more often than not, the board has an issue.